# Turn off Accessibility for iOS 8 app?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, accessibility

Is it possible to turn off accessibility for an iOS 8 app? I know apps are encouraged to use accessibility, and I plan on turning it on eventually, but need some time to get it updated first. I have tried setting:

```
self.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;
self.isAccessibilityElement = NO;

self.view.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;
self.view.isAccessibilityElement = NO;

tableView.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;
tableView.isAccessibilityElement = NO;
```

and nothing seems to work. The tableview headers, for both plain and grouped tableviews, still remain in large text in accordance with the accessibility settings of the device.

Comment: If you don't want the text to be enlarged, why not just turn off accessibility settings globally in your device options?

Comment: Do you mean turn them off for all apps? As an app developer, I was under the impression that I could not do that.

Comment: you're correct, I wasn't clear. I'm trying to understand _why_ you want to disable accessibility features for your app. What negative impact does having them enabled have?

Comment: I did not get my live app updated in time for iOS 8. Now all the fonts are messed up with the new forced accessibility feature. My cells are not the proper height. To fix everything properly will take some time. I do plan on adding this functionality, but until my app was ready, I wanted to disable it in an 'emergency' update.

Comment: I understand now. I don't have the answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, to the best of my understanding at this point, to turn off accessibility for an iOS 8 app (as a developer).